# set variable and get value on different task

Tags: java, android, gradle

So I have this task on Gradle:

```
task generateLibraryJar  << {
    exec {
        workingDir "library/"
        commandLine 'jar' , '-cvf', 'myLibrary.jar', '.'
    }
}
```

And I also have the following android config:

```
android {
    (...)
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField('String', 'MY_FIELD', '"Some value"')
        }
        release {
            buildConfigField('String', 'MY_FIELD', '"Some other value"')
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    (...)

}
```

I want gradle to generate a jar with a different name depending on the build type. i.e. I want it to generate `myLibrary-release.jar` for release and `myLibrary-debug.jar` for debug.

Is there a way to

1. get the current build type on this task
2. set a variable in either build type, then get its value on this task